# Radio buttons in bootstrap navigation bar

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, radio-button, navigationbar

I'm trying display some elements positioned in the center (like dropdown list) of nav bar. But my radio buttons doesn't want to get offset. What should I add to my code?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top second-navbar" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="container">
                <form role="form">
                    <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="gr" value="0" onchange="val(this)">Popular first</label>
                    <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="gr" value="1" onchange="val(this)">Newest first</label>
                </form>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button">
                    Items per page: <b>@Model.PagingInfo.ItemsPerPage</b>
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">10</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">20</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

[image: Bootstrap navigation bar]

Comment: You want dropdown in center?

Comment: @UbiquitousDevelopers No I want padding-top for radio buttons group like dropdown looks.

Comment: @UbiquitousDevelopers to set all elements in one line.

Comment: Remove class 'container' from li and override padding-top on '.navbar-nav > li > a' to 0. It will bring all elements in-line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add div with class radio. also you need to remove unnecessary tags

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top second-navbar" role="navigation">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="radio">
      <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="gr" value="0" onchange="val(this)">Popular first</label>
      <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="gr" value="1" onchange="val(this)">Newest first</label>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button">
                Items per page: <b>@Model.PagingInfo.ItemsPerPage</b>
                <span class="caret"></span>
            </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">10</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">20</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here is the codepen : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MKqwgJ

Answer (score 1):

There is slight change in your markup buddy. Just do these listed changes and it will be perfect as you wanted.

1.) remove the class `container` from your `<ul>` tag.

2.) To move the radio button to the left, add this bootstrap class to the radio button `<li>` tag.

`<li class="navbar-left">`

3.) To move the dropdown to the right, add this bootstrap class to the dropdown `<li>` tag.

`<li class="dropdown navbar-right">`

4.) Now for the top spacing, you need to give some padding to the radio button form just like the one dropdown list has.

```
form {
  padding: 10px 15px;
}
```

Voila ... perfectly aligned ! Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gmL1zt3s/1/)

Comment: Thanks for answer! But the first one solution is better for me because I have one more nav bar from above.

Comment: No worries. Glad you got the help you required.